# Strange adjusted (pseudo) p-values when running pairwise adonis

Tags: r, bioinformatics, p-value

I really need some input on an R bioinformatics issue. I suspect this might be a case of me not completely understanding the adjustment step when doing a pairwise anova (using this wrapper https://github.com/pmartinezarbizu/pairwiseAdonis). I've been googling around for a while now, and have not found any answer, so next step is trying here.

I've been using pairwise.adonis as a post hoc test after running the adonis test from the package vegan.

I've come across something I find a little strange, and I'm not sure if it's a bug, or if I've done something wrong, or if the data is just weird like that - any inputs would be much appreciated.

When I run the pairwise.adonis like this:

```
post_hoc_permanova <- pairwise.adonis(t(otu), meta$Fungicide_treatment, sim.function = "vegdist", 
sim.method = "bray", p.adjust.m = "fdr", reduce = NULL, perm = 999)
```

I get this  (sorry if the paste is a bit messy, not sure how to make it look pretty here):

```
post_hoc_permanova 

pairs Df SumsOfSqs F.Model R2 p.value p.adjusted sig
Bentonite vs Esquive 1 0.4309946 2.1228348 0.17511043 0.059 0.2400000
Bentonite vs Tessior 1 0.2354402 1.1522300 0.10331835 0.266 0.3855556
Bentonite vs Control water 1 0.2028768 1.0137438 0.09204353 0.346 0.3855556
Bentonite vs Copper oxychloride 1 0.1778650 1.0765919 0.09719523 0.347 0.3855556
Esquive vs Tessior 1 0.4197328 1.8764408 0.15799690 0.068 0.2400000
Esquive vs Control water 1 0.3258340 1.4845894 0.12926796 0.187 0.3740000
Esquive vs Copper oxychloride 1 0.4070595 2.2055388 0.18069983 0.072 0.2400000
Tessior vs Control water 1 0.2583331 1.1700713 0.10475057 0.288 0.3855556
Tessior vs Copper oxychloride 1 0.3041160 1.6361852 0.14061182 0.113 0.2825000
Control water vs Copper oxychloride 1 0.1205611 0.6636605 0.06223571 0.594 0.594000
```

I get all different p-values, but when they're adjusted, suddenly a lot of them have exactly the same adjusted values (e.g. p.adjusted sig = 0.2400000 for both p.value=0.059, 0.068 and 0.072). I'm at a loss to explain why this happens - if adjusting by any standard, the values would still be slightly different, depending on the "original" p-value, wouldn't they? If anyone can enlighten me, I'm all ears.

My dataset looks like this (full tables available here: https://github.com/Marieag/LeaSyBiome):

```
head(meta)
              
SampleID Real_Sample_Name Year Location Cultivar Fungicide_treatment 
GF.ITS.VL31 GF.ITS.VL31             <NA> 2022   Lisbon    Syrah           Bentonite 
GF.ITS.VL32 GF.ITS.VL32             <NA> 2022   Lisbon    Syrah           Bentonite 
GF.ITS.VL33 GF.ITS.VL33             <NA> 2022   Lisbon    Syrah           Bentonite 
GF.ITS.VL34 GF.ITS.VL34             <NA> 2022   Lisbon    Syrah           Bentonite 
GF.ITS.VL35 GF.ITS.VL35             <NA> 2022   Lisbon    Syrah           Bentonite 
GF.ITS.VL36 GF.ITS.VL36             <NA> 2022   Lisbon    Syrah           Bentonite
```

```
head(otu)
                    
GF.ITS.VL31  GF.ITS.VL32 GF.ITS.VL33  GF.ITS.VL34  GF.ITS.VL35 GF.ITS.VL36 GF.ITS.VL37  GF.ITS.VL38 
g__Kondoa            0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000           0 0.000000000 0.0000000000 
g__Sarocladium       0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000           0 0.000000000 0.0000000000 
g__Symmetrospora_1   0.001181818 0.0000000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000           0 0.000000000 0.0000000000 
o__Capnodiales       0.000000000 0.0006363636 0.004272727 0.0006363636 0.0004545455           0 0.001363636 0.0008181818 
s__Candida_cretensis 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000           0 0.000000000 0.0000000000 
c__Leotiomycetes     0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.001454545 0.0086363636 0.0008181818           0 0.001363636 0.0012727273 
GF.ITS.VL39  GF.ITS.VL40  GF.ITS.VL41  GF.ITS.VL42  GF.ITS.VL43  GF.ITS.VL44  GF.ITS.VL45 
g__Kondoa            0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 
g__Sarocladium       0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0025454545 0.0000000000 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 
g__Symmetrospora_1   0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 9.090909e-05 0.000000e+00 
o__Capnodiales       0.000000000 0.0005454545 0.0004545455 0.0002727273 0.0042727273 5.181818e-03 9.090909e-05 
s__Candida_cretensis 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 
c__Leotiomycetes     0.001454545 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0006363636 1.818182e-04 0.000000e+00 
GF.ITS.VL46 GF.ITS.VL47  GF.ITS.VL48  GF.ITS.VL49  GF.ITS.VL50  GF.ITS.VL51 GF.ITS.VL52 
g__Kondoa            0.0000000000           0 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000           0 
g__Sarocladium       0.0000000000           0 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000           0 
g__Symmetrospora_1   0.0000000000           0 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000           0 
o__Capnodiales       0.0007272727           0 0.0000000000 0.0003636364 0.0006363636 0.0000000000           0 
s__Candida_cretensis 0.0000000000           0 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000           0 
c__Leotiomycetes     0.0000000000           0 0.0007272727 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0001818182           0 
GF.ITS.VL53 GF.ITS.VL54 GF.ITS.VL56 GF.ITS.VL57  GF.ITS.VL58  GF.ITS.VL59 GF.ITS.VL60 
g__Kondoa                      0           0 0.000000000           0 9.090909e-05 0.0000000000           0 
g__Sarocladium                 0           0 0.000000000           0 0.000000e+00 0.0000000000           0 
g__Symmetrospora_1             0           0 0.000000000           0 0.000000e+00 0.0000000000           0 
o__Capnodiales                 0           0 0.001727273           0 3.636364e-04 0.0000000000           0 
s__Candida_cretensis           0           0 0.000000000           0 3.818182e-03 0.0002727273           0 
c__Leotiomycetes               0           0 0.000000000           0 0.000000e+00 0.0000000000           0
```

I hope someone out there can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: If `adonis` is using the Benjamini-Hochberg method for p-value adjustment then you should expect lots of the adjusted p-values to be the same because of how the method works.  You'll get a fuller explanation on Cross-Validated than here because this is not a programming question.

Comment: Thanks! I'll pop over there, then.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Answered it anyway (in anticipation of migration to Cross-Validated) and IMO the unadjusted p-values are reproducible dataset with respect to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'adjusted' values are often the same because of how the Benjamini-Hochberg method works.

The Benjamini-Hochberg adjusted p-values are calculated from the unadjusted p-values as follows:

1. First order the p-values from smallest to largest.
2. Multiply each by `N/i`, where `N` is the total number and `i` is the rank
   order
3. Set any values bigger than one to be equal to 1
4. Finally make sure the sequence always increases, by setting the adjusted p-value equal the subsequent value if the subsequent value is lower.

So your p-values are:

```
ps = c(0.059, 0.266, 0.346, 0.347, 0.068, 0.187, 0.072, 0.288, 0.113, 0.594)
```

if we sort them:

```
> p2 <- ps[order(ps)]
> p2
 [1] 0.059 0.068 0.072 0.113 0.187 0.266 0.288 0.346 0.347 0.594
```

now make the adjustment:

```
> pa <- p2 * 10/(1:10)
> pa
 [1] 0.5900000 0.3400000 0.2400000 0.2825000 0.3740000 0.4433333 0.4114286 0.4325000 0.3855556 0.5940000
```

You'll see that the 3rd value is 0.24, so we set the first and the second to 0.24 as well (because they were higher).  The ninth value is 0.3856, so we set the 6th to 8th to 0.3856 as well.  Then the final sequence will be the BH corrected values:

```
> p.adjust(p2[order(p2)], method="BH")
 [1] 0.2400000 0.2400000 0.2400000 0.2825000 0.3740000 0.3855556 0.3855556 0.3855556 0.3855556 0.5940000
```

And this is what you see in your table.

The wisdom of using a BH correction for post-hoc ANOVA comparisons is another question altogether!

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It makes a lot more sense now. I do realise that the BH correction is perhaps a little too, eh, lenient sometimes. What would would you recommend instead?

Comment: Not sure to be honest.  My understanding is that BH test works for independent hypotheses, and since these are generated as pairwise comparisons from a smaller number of groups they certainly aren't independent.  I've had very high error rates from BH test where statistics are essentially linear combinations of each other (like pathway enrichment for example).  For ANOVA we'd usually use Tukeys HSD, but I don't know how that can be applied to permanova.  I guess the adonis people have a good reason for choosing BH.  Interesting question anyway.

Comment: Also, from the names of your groups it looks like not every pairwise comparison is of equal interest, so consider that when thinking about multiple comparisons.